# API with Dynamic input param example

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-web-api, microservices

Team.
I am working on creating dynamic API for my application my API looks like below,

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("publish")]
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Publish(PublishEventDto publishEventDto)
    {
        await _eventDomain.PublishEventAsync(publishEventDto);
        return Ok();
    }
```

and dto structure will be

```
  public class PublishEventDto
{
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public dynamic Payload { get; set; }
}
```

now when I am trying to call my API it is showing double brace in input param I am unable to create object from it.

[image]

Comment: of cause you cant deserialize a dynamic. I'd use newtonsoft json and use JToken for partial deserialization

Comment: Or JElement in System.Text.Json

Comment: or depending on the case, make PublishEventDto generic and move your implementation to a generic base controller, then by adding a controller like: `class FooController : DtoController<Foo> { }` you can add support for a payload without much hassle. it's usually preferable to have models, but in the end that depend on what you're trying to accomplish here

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ExpandoObject or the object type as an alternative to dynamic.
It's work as a Dictionary

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).